# Twilio node extra parameters

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am making a call using twilio nodejs wrapper as below:

```
client.makeCall({

    to:'+1234567890',
    from: '+12345678',
    Method: "GET",
    url:'http://www.example.com/twilio-xml'
}, function(err, responseData) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(responseData.from);
        console.log(responseData.body);
    }
});
```

I would need to pass my custom parameters to `http://www.example.com/twilio-xml` request so that response twiml can be generated according to that. How can that be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

The easiest way to send extra parameters is to append them to the URL as querystring values:

```
url:'http://www.example.com/twilio-xml?foo=bar'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But, that doesn't seem to work. The call get disconnected immediately when attended.

Comment: If the call is getting immediately disconnected, it sounds like Twilio was unable to reterive the TwiML from the URL.  Can you try loading your URL in a browser or a tool like POSTMan to see if its returning valid TwiML?  Another option is to look at the App Monitor in your Twilio dashboard to see if Twilio encountered an error when it tried to get the TwiML: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor