# Twilio: Making conference name dynamic with REST apis

Tags: twilio

I am working on making conference calls from twilio client using REST apis.

I am using java helper libraries to call each participants and as they accept they are put to the same conference room. I am successful up to this. The code which returns the xml for conference, I have put in python following the code of server.py present in android sdk.

Currently in server.py I have hard coded the conference name, i.e anyone who tries for a conference will end up in same conference room.

So I want to make it dynamic. I want to pass the conference name from my java code to the url where server.py and the conference xml is present.

I have tried the following.

1. I tried adding one extra parameter to the call parameters as

   ```
   callParams.put("To", user); // Replace with a valid phone number
   callParams.put("ConfName", "kevin");
   callParams.put("From", my_twilio_num); // Replace with a valid phone number in your account
   callParams.put("Url", "https://dyno-name-conference.herokuapp.com/conference");
   final Call call = callFactory.create(callParams);
   ```

   where ConfName is my intended conference name. and I tried to retrieve it in server.py like

   ```
   ConfName = request.values.get('ConfName')
   response.dial(callerId=caller_id).conference(ConfName)
   ```

   But the ConfName is not getting retrieved.

   Is there a better approach for this.
2. I thought of passing an extra parameter along with the url as I see from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825829/twilio-node-extra-parameters). But I am not successful in that too.

May I know if there any correction in above approaches or a different approach for this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it work.

I used the url as

```
call__Params.put("Url", "https://dyno-name-conference.herokuapp.com/conference?conf_name=kevin");
```

and in server.py I accessed it as

```
conf_name = request.values.get('conf_name')
```